# useEffect getting triggered repeatedly even after applying [] brackets

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, use-effect, use-state

I was learning react and came across the concept of useEffect. So I was trying useEffects with resize event listeners and when doing so even after applying the square bracket which should be used only to run the useEffect once, I am repeatedly getting the updated size of the screen when trying the change the browser size.

below is the code, could some one please let me know if I have some code issue or is this how it is supposed to work?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// cleanup function
// second argument

const UseEffectCleanup = () => {
  const [size, setsize] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  const checkSize = () => {
    console.log("check size");
    setsize(window.innerWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect");
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkSize);
    return () => {
      console.log("Cleanup");
      window.removeEventListener("resize", checkSize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Windows Width</h2>
      <h2>{size}</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseEffectCleanup;
```

Comment: what are you getting in the console? Your useEffect is run once, but it only attaches the eventListener to your window. So when you're resizing your window, you go thru `checkSize`, then your `setsize` which trigger a re-render

Comment: Hi dbuchet, thanks for responding, it actually just prints the statement 'console.log("use effect");' only once however when we resize the window it updates the value of size useState, which as per my understanding should not be the case because of the [] brackets

Comment: Your useEffect is triggered only once, as expected. Once the event is attached to your window, there is nothing related to useEffect, it's just your listener callback which is triggered when your resize the window.

Comment: Thanks again, but I have just one more doubt.. wouldn't the removeEventListener removes the created event??

Comment: Not in your case. The returned function in your useEffect is executed when your component unmounts . If you had a dependency array, the fonction would be executed just before useEffect is re-triggered